# Passing data from controller to header in modal

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-modal

Please help me..

I want to pass some text from controller to modal in header tag..

This is what I want to send to header at modal from controller's method:

```
$this->labelFormTambah = "Edit Data Donatur";
```

And this is the attribute of the header that I want to send the data above:

```
<h3 class="modal-title" id="labelFormTambah" wire:model="labelFormTambah">
```

Sadly that doesn't work.

Any data sent from the same method to the same modal in input tags, is perfectly working.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: In laravel if you want to pass data to view you can write like this 
return view("edit.page",["lableForm" => "Edit Data Donatur"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion.

Your controller should look something like this:

```
public function edit(){
    //since you know the value of $this->labelFormTambah you can just pass it as an argument instead of creating a variable name first
    return view("edit.page",["lableForm" => "Edit Data Donatur"])
}
```

And then in your `edit page` your modal header should be like this:

```
<h3 class="modal-title" id="labelFormTambah" wire:model="labelFormTambah">{{$labelForm}}</h3> //the value in the double curly braces comes from the argument you've passed in your controller
```

And that will display your `$this->lableFormTambah` value that you returned along with your `view` as a value in your modal header tag

Comment: thx, it's working now..